# Shifting all element positions of an array in Python given by XOR operator

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, xor

I would like to know if there is a way to move all elements of a numpy array without iterating over each entry. The shift I desire is to relabel the indices by a fixed XOR operation, in the following form:

```
import numpy as np 

N = 2

x = np.arange(2**(2 * N)).reshape(2**N, 2**N)
z = np.zeros((2**N, 2**N))

k = 1

for i in range(2**N):
    for j in range(2**N):
        z[i][j] = x[i ^ k][j ^ k]
```

The problem I have is that latter I wish to take huge values of `N`, which becomes a bottleneck if we wish to iterate over each entry. Any advice on how to perform the move in a single shot will be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to preallocate `z`, make sure you allocate integers instead of floats. That alone may speed things up significantly for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simply no reason to use a loop here at all. You are not shifting anything, and the problem is completely separable across the axes:

```
x = np.arange(2**(2 * N)).reshape(2**N, 2**N)
z = x[np.arange(2**N)[:, None] ^ k, np.arange(2**N) ^ k]
```

But what is `x[a, b]` for some `a, b` to begin with? From the original definition, you can see that it's `a * 2**N + b`. You can therefore plug in `a = np.arange(2**N)[:, None] ^ k` and `b = np.arange(2**N) ^ k` to avoid having to generate anything but the final result:

```
idx = np.arange(2**N) ^ k
z = (idx[:, None] << N) + idx
```

It's generally faster to substitute `<< N` for `* 2**N`.

**Allocation**

None of the solutions shown here pre-allocate `z`. However, if you were to do that, as in the original question, you should be careful about the type.

```
z = np.zeros((2**N, 2**N))
```

This creates an array of floats by default, which is likely not what you want.

```
z = np.zeros((2**N, 2**N), dtype=int)
```

Adding an explicit `dtype` make the array into integers. However, the simplest method available to you is likely

```
z = np.zeros_like(x)
```

Since you are planning on filling in every single element, you don't need to waste time filling it with zeros first. `np.empty` presents a better option in this case:

```
z = np.empty((2**N, 2**N), dtype=int)
```

OR

```
z = np.empty_like(x)
```

Comment: Dear Mad Physicist, thank you for the answer. Apologies for not being very clear with my question. I just defined the array "x" as an example, in the practice, the matrix I am working with will have float type entries. However, you managed to cover what I wanted to know. Thank you so much, and also for the tips with the allocation.

Comment: @AlonsoViladomat. For future reference, when you want to demo floats, do something like `np.random.seed(1); np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(2**N, 2**N))`. That will discourage people like me from trying to find a pattern in the data or make it into integers for speed.